# How to implement a long-running, event-driven python program?

Tags: python

I have a series of maintenance tasks for a python WSGI application that are a bit too complex for a crontab (jobs need to be run at frequencies derived from the size of the job queue, manage a connection pool to a group of EC2 instances, etc).

How should I implement a long-running, event-driven python program? I've never needed this functionality before, so I'm not even sure what to google.

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ ?

Comment: @zengr, twisted and python-daemon are the first two things that come to mind, but I wanted to see if I was missing something in the standard library before I commit to anything. I'm still a bit new to python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the large, modern python sites are using [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for this type of work.  It is a distributed task queue that supports scheduling of tasks as well.

Though probably a bit heavyweight for a small site, it'll grow with you.  I'm looking to implement it myself (sans Rabbit) shortly.

I recently found another choice for django users, [django-tasks](http://code.google.com/p/django-tasks/) which is focused on fewer, longer, batch processing type jobs.  There is also [django-ztask](https://github.com/dmgctrl/django-ztask) using zeromq.

Addendum:  Just came across [gearman](http://gearman.org/) which has [python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gearman/2.0.2).

Comment: Ah, apparently the google query I was looking for was "python asynchronous task queue". :)